# Clojure - java interop - How to pass a float array>

Tags: java, clojure

I need to call a java function from clojure, which takes a float array as a parameter. How would I do this in clojure?

I tried

`(classname/function [0.1f 0.2f])` - but this doesn't work. Clearly the issue is with the parameter array. I can call other functions in the class with no problems, provide they don't take an array as a parameter.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

it looks like that function wants an array of GLfloats so the build in shortcut of `float-array` may not give you what you need. the general array builder function is
`(into-array type aseq)`

so it may look something like:

```
(def my-array (into-array GLfloat [0.0 0.0 0.0]))
```

into array is longer winded though more general.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`float-array`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/float-array). From the documetation:

```
user=> (doc float-array)
-------------------------
clojure.core/float-array
([size-or-seq] [size init-val-or-seq])
  Creates an array of floats
nil
user=> (float-array [1 2 3])
#<float[] [F@e1666>
user=>
```

Comment: Thank you. This didn't work for me. To be more specific, I am trying to call an opengl function.
In java, the code is like this:

GLfloat blackAmbientLight[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; 
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, blackAmbientLight);

However, I am not able to call the same from clojure :-(

The (float-array [0 0 0]) doesn't produce what I need when I pass the parameter